# Facebook canvas app redirected to m.facebook.com on iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

let me briefly explain my problem: I have an app (canvas app) on Facebook, which is also attached to fanpage as a page tab. Everything works great on desktop and android mobile devices, but I have a weird problem with iPhone users.

I am aware that page tabs are not supported on mobile devices, so redirect all users to a website where I detect device type (mobile/desktop). Then I redirect desktop users to a page tab on a fanpage, and mobile users directly to apps.facebook.com/APP_ID.

This works fine on Android devices, when users use browser access or Android official Facebook app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana).

This also works fine on iPhone when using direct browser (Safari) access. But when using official Facebook app for iPhone, it behaves very strangely: my website redirects it corretly to apps.facebook.com/APP_ID, but then immediately users are redirected to m.facebook.com whith message "Page cannot be found". Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Canvas is not available on mobile either – at most, users will get redirected to the Mobile Site URL you specified in app settings.

Comment: But this seems to be true only when using Facebook dedicated app on iPhone. When accessing through mobile web browser or through Facebook application for Android, it works correctly.